# Readability API confidence call returning 0.5 for any string passed to it

Tags: readability

Readability API offers a `/confidence` resource that returns the confidence that a given URL will be parsed nicely by the Readability parser. But the call returns 0.5 for [any random string passed to it](http://readability.com/api/content/v1/confidence?url=foo), even if it’s not a valid URL. Is this documented to be out of order somewhere? Getting the same average confidence for any article URL is not very helpful.